# How to use import () to dynamically load components in React?

Tags: reactjs, dynamic-import

I tried to use `import()` instead of `React.lazy` to dynamically load components, but it didn't work.

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
function App() {
  const [Com, setCom] = useState(null);

  const handleClick = () => {
      import("./A.js").then(c => {
        //console.log(c.default)
        setCom(c.default)
      }) 
  }

  return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Load</button>
        { Com ? <Com /> : null }
      </div>
   );
}

export default App;
```

A.js

```
import React from "react";

export default function A () {
    return (<div>A</div>)
}
```

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

In fact, I printed out `c.default`. It's really a function.

c.default

```
ƒ A() {
  return react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.createElement("div", {
    __source: {
      fileName: _jsxFileName,
      lineNumber: 4
    },
    __self: this
  }, "A");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, it's not related to the dynamic `import` but the `useState` implementation. For example:

```
import Comp from "./A";

function App() {
  const [Com, setCom] = useState(Comp);

  return (
    <div>
      <Com />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Will throw the same error. That's because when you call `useState(Comp)`, `Comp` "function" (which is the Component) been execute (you can test it by removing any `<Com />` from the code and adding `console.log` inside `A`. The `console.log` still appears).

As a result `Com` is no longer a Component but a JSX element. When you try to render JSX element in a function way (meaning wrapping it with `<` and `/>`, this error thrown.

The solution is either to set `Com` as a component (`() => Com`) or to render it as a JSX child (`{Com}`)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [Com, setCom] = useState(null);

  const handleClick = () => {
    import("./A.js").then(c => {
      //console.log(c.default)
      setCom(c.default);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Load</button>
      {/* <Comp /> */}
      {Com}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/answer-for-httpsstackoverflowcomq62125854863110-jj2wu

BTW, you can [see the difference](https://codesandbox.io/s/answer-for-httpsstackoverflowcomq62125854863110-kt2u0?file=/src/App.js) by `console.dir` the original outcome of `import Comp from "./A";` and the outcome of `useState(Comp)`

```
import Comp from "./A";

function App() {
  const [Com, setCom] = useState(Comp);
  // console.log(1, Com, 2, Comp);
  console.dir(Com) // Object
  console.dir(Comp) // ƒ A()
  //...
}
```

Comment: well actually I think react lazy is good. as I remember its only render when its need to and already give you back renderable compnent

Answer (score 3):

If setState is called with a function, it will be executed with the previous value as the argument.

```
const [count,setCount] = useState(0)
setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)
```

In your case, rather than updating the state with the imported function, React will execute it and the result will be set as the state.

Solution:

```js
setCom(() => c.default)
```